# Flat not projective, projective not free

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I am looking for examples of a flat but not projective module, and of a projective but not free module.

Comment: Note that torsion-free = flat for abelian groups

Comment: More generally, torsion-free = flat for modules over a Dedekind domain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The rational numbers are a flat but not projective $\mathbb Z$-module.

$\mathbb Z\oplus 0$ is a projective but not free 
$\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$-module.